# Does my computer fail to boot because I removed RAM?

Tags: windows-7, boot, memory, grub

I have a dual-boot (Windows 7 64-bit and Linux) system. A couple weeks ago I doubled my RAM from 4GB to 8GB. However, the new RAM was causing all sorts of boot problems with both Windows and Linux, so I removed it and went back to 4GB. Last night, I tried booting the Windows drive, using the GRUB boot-loader, but the computer will not boot. Linux boots fine, though. I tried running a system startup repair using the Windows install CD, but that did not work. I also ran a CHKDSK on it, which said there was nothing wrong with the system. So - is it possible that removing the RAM is what is causing Windows to not boot? Is it expecting 8GB and only finding 4GB, so it cannot run properly? I have a new set of 8GB of RAM on order, so if that is the problem, will installing the new RAM fix it? Or, do I need to rebuild Windows from scratch?

Thanks!

Comment: Its very unlikely ( 99.999% type change ) that Windows not booting has anything to do with you changing the amount of memory your system has.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it does not boot"?

Comment: After selecting Windows in GRUB, I get a black screen saying "Starting" and a flashing cursor, but it does not go any further than that.

Comment: Does the machine beep when it shows Starting?

Comment: No beep after GRUB. It does beep during POST. I am used to seeing the "Starting" screen for a second or two, then the Windows 7 loading screen.

Comment: It is more likely that the "boot problems" you experienced have damaged the windows install. Since the Windows startup repair didn't fix it, a reinstall is definitely on the cards.

Comment: Can you start it in safe mode?

Comment: It has been awhile since I have done any "reinstall" with Windows. Has Microsoft improved the process so I can just install Windows without losing all my old data? Most of it is backed up, but if I don't have to reinstall all my programs, that would be wonderful.